# Hundreds of markers moving simultaneously. Bad performance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api v3, and i need to move many(hundreds) of markers at the same time. From server, i get array of objects, representing a marker with it´s coordinates as it moved over time(few months), ordered by time when it moved. Above my map, i have a progress bar representing time with "month:year" text. What my code does, is move the marker(and draw polyline) at the exact time so it fits the time currently displayed on the "time progress bar". At every position where the marker stops, i leave a new marker to show the history of the movement. The whole process repeats over and over(setInterval() function). My code is working, the problem is performance, so i am asking: is there any way i could improve the performance ? some better way than i am doing it? there must be something. Here is my code:

```
if (mapOverTime != null) {
    trackables.forEach(function (trackable) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: mapOverTime,
            draggable: false,
            clickable: false,
            icon: geoIcon,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.none,                                
            zIndex: 2
        });            

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
        polyline.setMap(mapOverTime);
        // adding these to arrays so i can access and remove them from the map later
        markersArray.push(marker);
        polylineArray.push(polyline);
        trackable.years.forEach(function(year) {
            $.each(year.months, function(index, month) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (month.coordinates.length > 0) {
                        var moveCounter = month.coordinates.length;
                        var timeToMove = Math.floor(pause_interval / moveCounter);
                        $.each(month.coordinates, function(i, position) {
                            var latTo = position.latitude;
                            var lngTo = position.longitude;
                            var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latTo, lngTo);
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                moveToPosition(marker, destination, polyline);
                            }, (i) * timeToMove);
                        });
                    }
                }, pause_interval * index);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This is the function making the moves happen:

```
function moveToPosition(marker, destination, polyline) {
  // current path of the polyline
  var path = polyline.getPath();
  // add new coordinate
  path.push(destination);
  // rendering whole line would make the map even more chaotic, this makes the line dissapear after 8 moves of the marker
  if (path.getLength() > 8) // comment out to render whole 
      th.removeAt(0); // path of polyline
  // set marker position to the new one
  marker.setPosition(destination);
  // render new marker on this position so that it is well visible where the coins were
  var historyPoint = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapOverTime,
    draggable: false,
    icon: historyIcon,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.none,
    zIndex: 0
  });
  historyPoint.setPosition(destination);
  // again add to global array so i can set access and remove this marker from the map later
  historyPoints.push(historyPoint);        
}
```

The only thing i do, is iterate through all the markers and it´s coordinates, move marker at given time, draw line behind it, create new marker at the new position, and go for another coordinates. When 1 iteration end, all the objects are removed from the map and the process starts again. Any idea how to improve performance? or the only solution is to decrease the number of markers i want to render? Thank you for your opinions!

Comment: Just for fun, could you increment a counter when a new marker is created, and let that page run for a minute, then see how many markers there are? (Or maybe just look at `historyPoints.length`)

Comment: I get around 26 000 coordinates totally, spread between approximately 250 markers. That means average of 104 "history points" per marker. Time span is 7 months = 15 moves in month per marker. It should take approximately 10 seconds to render all the moves of one month :)

Comment: So, the amount of markers is way over "hundreds", more like "ten thousands"... That can't possibly run quickly.

Comment: You might want to post your code over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `th.removeAt(0); // path of polyline`  - that should be `path`, not `th`, right?

Comment: Yes, probably a mistake when copying the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Why bother specifying `animation: google.maps.Animation.none,`?  If you're not using it, just remove it.  And according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Animation), there are two values, `BOUNCE` and `DROP`, so there isn't a `none` value anyway.
- Use standard javascript array looping, instead of jquery's `$.each()` if you can; [it's faster](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551)
- You create two variables just for the benefit of specifying your destination coordinates.  You use them once, and never again, so why not just use the original values?  i.e.

  ```
  var latTo = position.latitude;
  var lngTo = position.longitude;
  var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(latTo, lngTo);
  ```

just becomes

```
    var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
```

- Another improvement you could make here.  Use the shorthand inline struct notation for specifying your destination coordinates.  It should reduce some overhead in creating hundreds of LatLng objects.  i.e.

  ```
  var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
  ```

then becomes:

```
    var destination = {lat: position.latitude, lng: position.longitude};
```

- You create a polyline, then you set the map:

  ```
  var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
  polyline.setMap(mapOverTime);
  ```

I see this all the time and never understand it... just add `map: mapOverTime` to the polyOptions, saves having to do an additional function call.

- Similarly with historyPoint... don't call `setPosition()` on it, just specify `position: destination` in the options you pass when you create the marker

All these are minor things which will likely make little different to trying to move hundreds of markers at once, but I'd still recommend you try them anyway.

Comment: [It's something...](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/289/b/b/it__s_something_by_rober_raik-d4czhxe.png)

Comment: Thank tou for your suggestions, i appreciate that, and it certainly will help. Despite that, i was thinking more like if there isn't some different approach i might choose, improving the performance fundamentally :)